# Enter function with vba: Concatenate column with i row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract date from a string:

> Thu Feb 25 16:13:15 PST 2016

My macro enters the function , however, it doesn't concatenate properly the column with i so it will be for specific row number.
Instead I get this:

> =CONCATENATE(MID("J" & i,5,6),",",RIGHT("J" & i,4))

Please help me to concatenate. Thank you

```
Sub FormatDate()
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To FinalRow
    Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(MID(""B"" & i,5,6),"","",RIGHT(""B"" & i,4))"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little different approach that results in a "real" date, that you can use in calculations, without entering a formula into the cell.  I did format it to look the same as the result of your formula, but you could format it however you want.

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub FormatDate()
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim V As Variant
Dim I As Long

    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 12).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 3 To FinalRow
        V = Split(Cells(I, "B"))
        V(1) = Month(DateValue(V(1) & " 01")) 'Change month string into number.

        Cells(I, 12) = DateSerial(V(5), V(1), V(2))
        Cells(I, 12).NumberFormat = "mmm dd yyyy"
    Next I

End Sub
```

---

There are other ways of processing the date:

---

```
For I = 3 To FinalRow
    V = Split(Cells(I, "B"))
    Cells(I, 12) = DateValue(V(1) & " " & V(2) & " " & V(5))
    Cells(I, 12).NumberFormat = "mmm dd yyyy"
Next I
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You have your quotes in the wrong places:

```
Cells(i, 12).Formula = "=CONCATENATE(MID(B" & i & ",5,6),"","",RIGHT(B" & i & ",4))"
```